# How to build a header only lib without inline statment for each function?

Tags: c++, inline

In my code, I have standard and templatized functions. It seems to me that it is not good practice to have the declaration of standard functions in foo.h, their definition in foo.cpp, and the definition of template functions in foo.h. It's a little messy to have definition in both files. Like that :

*foo.h*

```cpp
//Declaration of standard function
void stdFunc(int i);

//Definition of template function
template<typename T>
inline void templFunc(const T& t){
  cout << t << endl;
}
```

*foo.cpp*

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

//Definition of standard function
void stdFunc(int i){
  cout << i << endl;
}
```

So I decided to define my functions in the headers. But now, all functions need to have the inline statment to avoid linker error, which is not recommended either.
How do header-only libraries like [Boost](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) or [CGAL](https://www.cgal.org/) to not declare all their functions as inline ?

Comment: `How do header-only libraries like Boost or CGAL to not declare all their functions as inline ?` By not defining them in the header.

Comment: You have declaration and definition terms reversed. If it has a body, it is a definition. Why are inline functions not recommended? That is the standard practice for header-only libs. Also, the definition of header-only lib is having no `.cpp` files so it is not like you have a choice anyway.

Comment: Why did you inline your template function? They are naturally allowed to appear multiple times, everywhere the template is instantiated.

Comment: @Quimby That's right, sorry, I corrected it. I have read that it is not good to use the `inline` keyword  too much. Something about the compiler doing a better optimization.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow okay I see, I will remove inline statment for template

Comment: Note only some of Boost is header only: [Header-Only Libraries](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries) _"...The only Boost libraries that must be built separately are:..."_

Comment: *" I have read that it is not good to use the inline keyword too much."* The key phrase here is "too much". That doesn't mean "not at all", but "only when needed". This might be one of those cases.

Comment: @MaximeCharrière Inline functions should improve performance if anything, certainly not worsen it. Because the compiler will have access to the implementation in contrast to separately compiled object files which require link-time optimization to allow cross-module optimizations. Compilation times on the other hand can be considerably worse because each TU which includes this header also compiles the function, leading to many duplicates which are then just thrown away by the linker.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a header-only library then it must only contain templates or inline functions. There is no other way.

Note: inline has nothing to do with inlining but means the function may appear multiple times in the translation units without giving a duplicate defintion error when linking.

It's a promise that all the ocurances of the functions will be the same and the linker shall pick one of them as the representing object.

Comment: Okay, I see. I will create templates and inline functions.